# $\frac{1}{D+1} e^x$

Tags: differential-operators

How do I evaluate $$\dfrac{1}{D+1} e^x$$ where $D$ is the differential operator?

I have tried using series expansion, but it just doesn't seem right to me:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(-D)^ke^x$$

Comment: How should one interpret this notation? Does $\frac1{D+1}$ mean $(D+I)^{-1}$?

Comment: $e^x$ is an eigenfunction of $D$ with eigenvalue $1$. Any sensible interpretation of the expression $\frac{1}{D+1}e^x$ will give you $\frac{1}{2}e^x$.

Comment: @achillehui Plus the kernel $ce^{-x}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the notation is to be interpreted as $(D+I)^{-1}$, then you are looking for function(s) $y$ such that 
$$(D+I)y=e^x.$$
This is equivalent to solving the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=e^x.$$

Multiplying throughout by $e^x$, we get
$$e^x\,\frac{dy}{dx}+e^xy=e^{2x}\implies \frac{d}{dx}(ye^x)=e^{2x},$$
and integrating both sides yields the general solution $\boxed{y(x) = \tfrac12e^x + ce^{-x}}$, where $c$ is the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation : $$(D-a)y = f (x)$$

i.e. $$ (Dy - ay ) = f(x)$$

Now multiply both sides by $e^{-ax}$ ( integrating factor )

You can see that :

$$ (e^{-ax}Dy -e^{-ax}ay ) = f(x)e^{-ax}$$

Which indeed reduces to :

$$D(e^{-ax} y) = e^{-ax}f(x)$$

Integrate on both sides we get:

$$(D-a) ^{(-1)}f (x) = e^{ax}\int e^{-ax} f(x) dx.$$

Put $a= -1$

Now the integral becomes

$$ e^{-x}\int e^{x}e^{x}dx$$

Which indeed equals to $(1/2) e^x$ ( without considering constant of integration .

Comment: It is not really obvious to me, can you please explain why this property holds?

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide a proof for the formula included in the Hint section?

Comment: Consider the answer by @Luis Collins . substitute $e^{ax}\int e^{-ax} f(x) dx$ for  $y$  see the result.

Comment: See the edit @ Max Wong

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.